# What do handle_external_interrupt (in vmx.c) do?

Tags: interrupt, kvm

In theory, external interrupts of guest VM are injected by KVM through "interrupt window", then what do handle_external_interrupt (in vmx.c) do? From the perspective of source code, it does nothing but recording.

Answer (score 0):

One possible use is to trigger a vmexit for remote guest tlb flush IPIs.
You can check the kvm_vcpu_kick function in the kvm kernel module.

Comment: When referring IPI, you mean Inter Processor Interrupt? It seems right. Thx! If you don't mind, could you give me more information about TLB flush. Here is the question: does "TLB flush" mean "write back sequencially"?